# How do I replace the null element in django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model as such:

```
actual = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

What I want to do is tell the model that whenever it null, I want the integer to be 0. How would I do so. I tried the following

```
actual = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=0)
```

This did not work.

Comment: what did not work? you are already setting the default value to 0. Also, `null=0` (well, the valid syntax is `null=False`) is not needed as the columns are non-nullable by default. If you want to be able to edit the existing records, you can open the shell, and update the values.. `MyModel.objects.filter(actual__isnull=True).update(actual=0)`

Comment: It cannot be null if the default is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
actual = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

will allow for the model to not be null while giving it default of 0.

Answer (score 0):

The Django documentation states that when the null field option is "True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database. **Default is False**."

So, by default this should work.

```
actual = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/